# ContentChildren angular 2 and reference to a HTMLElement

Tags: angular-components

I have a Component and I use it in this way:

```
<ImgList>
    <img src="../assets/img/file1.jpg" width="30px" height="20px" />
    <img src="../assets/img/file2.jpg" width="30px" height="20px" />
</ImgList>
```

I want in `export class ImgListComponent` to take a reference to the first image, I tried:

```
@ContentChildren('img', {read: ElementRef}) imgEls: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

and in:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.imgEls.toArray[0])

  }
```

but console displays undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `ContentChild` and `ContentChildren` isn't a CSS selector but a component reference. You can create a fake component to reference all the images, like:

```
@Directive({selector: 'img[foo]'}) exports class ImageDirective {}
```

then you can implement your `ContentChildren` in this way:

```
@ContentChildren(ImageDirective) imgEls: QueryList<ImageDirective>;
```

remember to declare the new directive in your module.